# Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "localhost" using Testcafe in Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to set up a bitbucket pipeline to run our end-to-end testing using testcafe for our angular application.

We are using the guide from this link: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402821/guides/continuous-integration/bitbucket-pipelines

But after running it in the bitbucket pipeline, we always get the below error. It is because locally, we are running it at the localhost:3200 which is not the case in bitbucket.

```
Error in fixture.beforeEach hook -
      Failed to load the page at "http://localhost:3200/projects/list".
      Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the "retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.
      You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".
      Error details:
      Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "http://localhost:3200/projects/list".
      Browser: Chrome 94.0.4606.81 / Linux 0.0
```

Comment: This error means that TestCafe failed to load a page specified as a test or a fixture page. It should be specified using the web app port. Please make sure that your web app port is 3200 or change the port value to the correct one in your test code.

Comment: @AlexKamaev Thank you for your comment. How can I specify the web app port? Is it possible through a command one?

Comment: This is the port of your application. It is not related to TestCafe. You need to determine the port on which you are running your application and use it in your test when specifying the page URL.